# Is there a way to change meta tag content dynamiclly without javascript and SSR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is no image to the shared Url link in social media.

I have React app (online shop). I change dynamiclly og:image and og:title meta tags using:

```
document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]')?.setAttribute('content', `https://www.example.com${product.img}`)
```

However, when I shared the URL link in social media the image didn't display. I know social media doesn't read javascript and because of this I'm looking for another way.

Comment: No. You need to put the tag in the content generated by the server. Whether you use React SSR for that or something else does not matter.

Comment: I've done that but the app has to be refreshed every time when I select some product to get new content from the server.  I don't want to refresh the app and because of this I'm looking for another way.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the app has to be refreshed every time*"? Notice that any kind of URL preview generation will not "select some product", it will just load the html page for that particular URL.

Comment: I mean when I navigate to some product the URL is changed, but the meta tags are not changed. Then I have to refresh the page to get new meta tag content from the server.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't matter. The preview generation code will not navigate around your page.

Answer (score 0):

Most pages like social media or search engines will not execute any client side JavaScript.
They just load the basic html-page itself and use the information which is in that.
Your meta tag will not be changed then.

So the meta tag would need to be set dynamically on server side not on client side.
To answer on how to do that, we might need to know which runtime is running on the server.